Can't Display title nor description for some reason
Well, I am passing a titles, description and Link as props to child component the Link is working but the title or description isn't displaying
this is the child component
"use client";

import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { MdArrowOutward } from "react-icons/md";

gsap.registerPlugin(); // Assuming you don't use ScrollTrigger

type ContentListProps = {
  items: { title: string; description: string; link: string }[];
  viewMoreText: string;
};

export default function ContentList({
  items,
  viewMoreText = "Read More",
}: ContentListProps) {
  const itemsRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement[]>([]); // Updated useRef type

  useEffect(() => {
    // Animate list-items in with a stagger
    itemsRef.current.forEach((item, index) => {
      gsap.fromTo(
        item,
        { opacity: 0, y: 20 },
        { opacity: 1, y: 0, duration: 1.3, ease: "elastic.out(1,0.3)", stagger: 0.2 }
      );
    });
  }, [items]); // dependency on items only


  return (
    <ul className="grid border-b border-b-slate-100">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index} className="list-item opacity-0">
          <a href={item.link} className="flex flex-col justify-between border-t border-t-slate-100 py-10 text-slate-200 md:flex-row ">
            <div className="flex flex-col">
              <span className="text-3xl font-bold">{item.title}</span>  {/* Title */}
              <p className="text-lg text-gray-500">{item.description}</p>  {/* Description */}
            </div>
            <span className="ml-auto flex items-center gap-2 text-xl font-medium md:ml-0">
              {viewMoreText} <MdArrowOutward />  {/* Read More Text */}
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}


this is the parent component
import Bounded from "@/Components/Bounded";
import Heading from "@/Components/Heading";
import { Content, isFilled } from "@prismicio/client";
import { PrismicRichText, SliceComponentProps } from "@prismicio/react";
import ContentList from "./ContentList";
export type ContentIndexProps = SliceComponentProps<Content.ContentIndexSlice>;
const projects = [
  { title: "Project 1", description: "This is project 1", link: "https://www.google.com/" },
  { title: "Project 2", description: "This is project 2", link: "https://www.google.com/" },
  { title: "Project 3", description: "This is project 3", link: "https://www.google.com/" },
];
const ContentIndex = ({ slice }: ContentIndexProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Bounded
      data-slice-type={slice.slice_type}
      data-slice-variation={slice.variation}
    >
      <Heading size="xl" className="mb-8">
        {slice.primary.heading}
      </Heading>
      {isFilled.richText(slice.primary.description) && (
        <div className="prose prose-xl prose-invert mb-10">
          <PrismicRichText field={slice.primary.description}/>
        </div>
      )}
      <ContentList items={projects} viewMoreText="Read More" />      
    </Bounded>
  );
};
export default ContentIndex;

Literally tried everything, the thing is the Link is working but the texts are not rendering or displaying, I want item.title and the item.description and viewMoretext to display

The code seems fine)?), did you try to console.log items in child components and see what displays, also check the HTML code with inspect elements maybe the title and description are displaying but some CSS classes are being applied to it and they are not visible

Yeah the opacity was creating problems but now I don't know how to put the same styling without opacity

just remove the opacity-0 from className="list-item opacity-0" and keep the rest as is
